# Building Micronaut docker image in GitlabRunner with docker executor

Tags: java, docker, gradle, gitlab, micronaut

**TLDR:** How can one build docker images with Gradle inside a Openjdk container?

## The problem

We are building a [Micronaut](https://micronaut.io) based suite of microservices in a multi-module Gradle project using GitLab pipelines.

Currently our pipeline builds docker images in a separate pipeline stage using docker command line, but it is starting to become unwieldy and cumbersome to add new services that way.

So instead of having separate pipeline steps for building the executable and then building docker images for each executable, I am looking into building the docker images right along with the main build step using gradle.

[Micronaut's gradle plugin](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-gradle-plugin) includes and extends [gradle-docker-plugin](https://bmuschko.github.io/gradle-docker-plugin/current/user-guide/) and allows building docker images using `dockerBuild` task.

The whole Gradle build step is executed from within `openjdk:14` docker image by custom private `gradle-runner` instance, so that container doesn't have any docker related bits on it.

## What I've tried so far

### The naive approach

My first attempt was to simply add `dockerBuild` target to the Gradle command line. That one failed as expected with the following stacktrace (abbreviated for the sake of clarity):

```
Execution failed for task ':my-service:dockerBuild'.
> com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to http://127.0.0.1:2375 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':my-service:dockerBuild'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:188)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    /.../
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
> Task :my-service:dockerBuild FAILED
Building image using context '/builds/my-group/my-project/my-service/build/docker'.
Using Dockerfile '/builds/my-group/my-project/my-service/build/docker/Dockerfile'
Using images 'registry.gitlab.com/my-group/my-project/my-service:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT+4b9f8460.179'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    /.../
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to http://127.0.0.1:2375 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
    at com.github.dockerjava.httpclient5.ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl.execute(ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl.java:153)
    at com.github.dockerjava.httpclient5.ApacheDockerHttpClient.execute(ApacheDockerHttpClient.java:8)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.execute(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:228)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.lambda$executeAndStream$1(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:269)
Caused by: com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to http://127.0.0.1:2375 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory$1.run(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:87)
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:84)
    /.../
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:67)
    at com.github.dockerjava.httpclient5.ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl.execute(ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl.java:149)
    ... 3 more
```

After some initial headschratching I figured out that this was basically caused by the fact that a build running in a container simply did not have access to docker engine remote api.

### Docker socket approach

Couple of mediocre applications of *Google-Fu* later, I found the recommendation to map `/var/run/docker.sock` into the container file system.

This prompted me to modify my gitlab-runner configuration:

```ini
[[runners]]
  name = "gennet-elab jdk runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    image = "openjdk:14.0.2-slim"
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", ...]
```

Running the pipeline with that configuration yielded me the following failure stacktrace:

```
Execution failed for task ':my-service:dockerBuild'.
> java.io.IOException: native write() failed : Connection reset by peer
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':my-service:dockerBuild'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:188)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
    [...]
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: native write() failed : Connection reset by peer
    at com.github.dockerjava.httpclient5.ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl.execute(ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl.java:153)
    at com.github.dockerjava.httpclient5.ApacheDockerHttpClient.execute(ApacheDockerHttpClient.java:8)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.execute(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:228)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.lambda$executeAndStream$1(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:269)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: native write() failed : Connection reset by peer
    at com.github.dockerjava.httpclient5.UnixDomainSocket$UnixSocketOutputStream.write(UnixDomainSocket.java:319)
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.shaded.org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:117)
    [...]
    at com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:67)
    at com.github.dockerjava.httpclient5.ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl.execute(ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl.java:149)
    ... 3 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: native write() failed : Broken pipe
        at com.github.dockerjava.httpclient5.UnixDomainSocket$UnixSocketOutputStream.write(UnixDomainSocket.java:319)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.shaded.org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:117)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.shaded.org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flush(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:126)
        [...]
        at com.github.dockerjava.httpclient5.ApacheDockerHttpClient.execute(ApacheDockerHttpClient.java:8)
        at com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.execute(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:228)
        at com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.lambda$executeAndStream$1(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:269)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

This suggests to me, it tries to connect over the socket, but the connection is closed by docker API server.

From all that I can understand, the problem might have something to do with docker api security, but all of the tutorials out there show dind (Docker in Docker) usage and that does not really help my use case.

I've also tried running the container with privileged access and tried once with dind service attached to the build job, but none of these seemed to work.

## The Question

So, the question for the Great and Powerful Internet is if there is a way to build docker images using Gradle inside openjdk container and leveraging Docker remote API?

If yes, what am I missing? If no, what are the alternatives (yes, I know I can probably just create a separate gitlab shell runner, but I'd like to explore the Docker option first)

Answer (score 1):

I've get the same issue, and so far I wasn't able to solve it (having a docker daemon alongside the jdk container, entreprise restriction :/)
But, there is a workaround, is using the [gradle-jib-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin), which will let you build docker images for each of your module, and thus without any docker daemon (magic !)

Comment: Yes, I found the `gradle-jib-plugin` as well. It's a decent work-around. 
Wish Micronaut folks would migrate their official docker support over to it...